# hector quadrotor catkin_make error

Tags: hector-quadrotor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I was trying to build "hector_quadrotor_tutorial" by "catkin_make". Under worksapce directory, I enterned

> catkin_make

it shows

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by"gazebo_ros_control" with any of the following names:

gazebo_ros_controlConfig.cmake
gazebo_ros_control-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "gazebo_ros_control" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
set "gazebo_ros_control_DIR" to a directory containing one of the abovefiles.  If "gazebo_ros_control" provides a separate development package orSDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
hector_quadrotor/hector_quadrotor_controller_gazebo/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/xiaohao/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/xiaohao/hector_quadrotor_tutorial/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

I already tried

> source /devel/setup.bash

I'm not sure how it goes wrong. Any advice aprreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210564/hector-quadrotor-catkin_make-error/) by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 40 on 2015-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

its been solved in two steps,

1. reinstall libsdformat1.Because I removed "libsdformat" when I was trying to install sdformat.

   $ sudo apt-get install libsdformat1
2. install unmet packages

   $ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control

---

Originally posted by [Glen](https://answers.ros.org/users/19650/glen/) with karma: 40 on 2015-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [naveed](https://answers.ros.org/users/35723/naveed/) on 2018-06-07**:
I have a similar problem but your solution didnt work for me. Any other tips ?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, for the hydro disto you need to install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-gazebo-ros-control
```

---

Originally posted by [angelos.p](https://answers.ros.org/users/22933/angelos.p/) with karma: 148 on 2015-06-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1